# Upload data from django to AWS S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am learning django and AWS from this [site](http://%20https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com).

I tried to point 'dropbox' to my bucket but in vain. I don't have a file selection button.

It looks like this:

[image]

while should be:

[image]

Am I missing something?

I am using Python v. 3.7.1, Django v 2.1.7. 
I tried to search for this issue in many websites but couldn't succeed in finding a solution.

Here is my code:

storage_backends.py

```
class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

settings.py

```
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static'),
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'xxx'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload = models.FileField()
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Document


class DocumentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Document
    fields = ['upload', ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        documents = Document.objects.all()
        context['documents'] = documents
        return context
```

home.html

```
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Uploaded at</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for document in documents %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ document.upload.url }}" target="_blank">{{ document.upload.name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ document.uploaded_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ document.upload.size|filesizeformat }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">No data.</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code compiles fine.